# Information cannot be obtained from shared link URLs created by others

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to see the shared link information from the OneDrive shared link URL.
If you use the shared link URL created by yourself (test001) as a parameter, you will succeed in getting the information.

```
string sharingUrl = "https://test001-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/test001_...";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');
var item = await graphClient.Shares[encodedUrl].Request().GetAsync();
```

When trying to get information from a shared link URL created by another user (test002)

```
string sharingUrl = "https://test001-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/test002_...";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');
var item = await graphClient.Shares[encodedUrl].Request().GetAsync();
```

System.NullReferenceException occurs in the above process.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to access that link on the browser? Also check the sharing setting in your sharepoint admin center whether this is allowed or not.

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Anonymous shared link that can be accessed from a browser.
I didn't know about the SharePoint admin center, so let's check it.

Comment: I confirmed that sharing settings are allowed in the SharePoint admin center.

When I signed in to the owner in Graph Explorer and called to get the shared link information with the encoded URL, I was able to get the information.
When I signed in with another person and called for information acquisition of the shared link with the same parameters, the connection was disconnected on the server side.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with API calls and Graph Explorer calls, so I decided that at this point, others can't get the shared link information.

Comment: Please check if you have granted read permissions to the other user using this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I was successfully able to test the data for scope= "organisation".

Comment: Does it mean granting direct access and then accessing the information on the shared link?
I want to get information about shared links without direct access.

Comment: I have tried to test it without granting access and it didn't work. So yes, you need to grant access first and then try to access it if you use this API.

Comment: Thank you for checking the operation.
It seems to be the same result, and I was relieved to find that this procedure was not wrong.
Since there is a discrepancy between the expected behavior and the API specifications, change the behavior of the program to be created.